# What is the most efficient way of using boto with EC2 for processing on server and fetching results back?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, rsync, boto

I am toying with EC2 and here is my scenario :

One time : Created an EC2 instance with the necessary key pair.

Daily :

```
fire up an EC2 instance.
send a file of IDs to EC2 micro-instance from local machine.
fire a python script to process the IDs and generate an output file.
fetch the output file to the local machine from the EC2 instance.
stop the EC2 instance.
```

factors :

```
I am using the same EC2 instance every time I want to process this file.
I want to keep costs down, so I want to cron the whole process to start and stop at a certain time interval.
```

Rough code :

```
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'yourkey'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'yoursecret'

conn = EC2Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)


reservation = conn.run_instances('ami-5647a33f', instance_type='m1.micro', key_name='mykey')

instance = reservation.instances[0]

while not instance.update() == 'running':
  time.sleep(5)

## Fetch the file from local machine
## --> Do the processing here --<
## send the file back to the local machine

# time up for the day, stop it
instance.stop()
```

Right now, I am manually starting and stopping the EC2 instance and rsync'ing the file back and forth. I want to eliminate this step. Is this the best way of doing it or do you have any suggestions? If you can add some lines to the code with a sample input file from local machine (abc.txt) and print the contents of the file at ec2 and output that to a out.txt and fetch it back. That file transfer without password prompts is proving to be a challenge. (will eventually add to hosts file but didn't look into it yet)

Thank you SOers!

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a far ranging question, but you want to have boto start the instance for you, poll EC2 to wait for the instance to be started, and then use rsync with [passwordless logins](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/25/how-to-set-up-a-password-less-ssh-login/) to transfer the files back and forth.  Once the processing is done you can have boto shut the instance back down.